Connect my Viewer app to an Autodesk Construction Cloud project
I'm exploring the Autodesk Viewer SDK for viewing CAD models enriched with custom data sources. I have created a test app and I have been invited as a "Developer" to our company Autodesk Construction Cloud (ACC) account. I have been added to a test project hosted under this account. As part of the invitation process, I have integrated my app with the account by providing the required secrets. How can I now access the 3D models hosted in Document Management in the test project I have access to?

You can use the Data Management API. A good starting place is the Hubs Browser tutorial. My issue was that the administrator forgot to accept my integration request after I have accepted the invitation and filled out the integration details.
